# Breaking TensorFlow gradient calculation into two (or more) parts

Tags: tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

Is it possible to use TensorFlow's `tf.gradients()` function in parts, that is - calculate the gradient from of loss w.r.t some tensor, and of that tensor w.r.t the weight, and then multiply them to get the original gradient from the loss to the weight?

For example, let `W,b` be some weights, let `x` be an input of a network, and let `y0` denote labels.

Assume a forward graph such as

```
h=Wx+b
y=tanh(h)
loss=mse(y-y0)
```

We can calculate `tf.gradients(loss,W)` and then apply (skipping some details) `optimizer.apply_gradients()` to update `W`.

I then try to extract an intermediate tensor, by using `var=tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(...)`, and then calculate two gradients: `g1=tf.gradients(loss,var)` and `g2=tf.gradients(var,W)`.
I would then, by the chain rule, expect the dimensions of `g1` and `g2` to work out so that I can write `g=g1*g2` in some sense, and get back `tf.gradients(loss,W)`.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. The dimensions are incorrect. Each gradient's dimensions will be that of the "w.r.t variable", so there won't be a correspondence between the first gradient and the second one. What am I missing, and how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.gradients` will sum over the gradients of the input tensor. To avoid it you have to split the tensor into scalars and apply `tf.gradients` to each of them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones([1, 10])

w = tf.get_variable("w", initializer=tf.constant(0.5, shape=[10, 5]))
out = tf.matmul(x, w)
out_target = tf.constant(0., shape=[5])

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(out - out_target))

grad = tf.gradients(loss, x)

part_grad_1 = tf.gradients(loss, out)
part_grad_2 = tf.concat([tf.gradients(i, x) for i in tf.split(out, 5, axis=1)], axis=1)

grad_by_parts = tf.matmul(part_grad_1, part_grad_2)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([grad]))
    print(sess.run([grad_by_parts]))
```

Comment: How do I know where to split, if for instance I have a 3D or larger tensor? and what about minibatches?

Comment: @yoki you will have to split everywhere, along all dimensions until only scalars are left. Here are some more informations: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients), `tf.gradients` (emphasis mine)

> constructs symbolic derivatives of **sum** of ys w.r.t. x in xs.

If any tensor in `ys` in multidimensional, it is `reduce_sum`med before the resulting list of scalar is itself summed, before being differenciated. This is why the output gradient has the same size as the `xs`.

This also explain why losses can be multidimensional in tensorflow: they are implicitely summed over before differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

for future readers:

Tensorflow has made some advancements, and as for tf2.7 (and maybe even earlier versions) **you can use tf.GradientTape.jacobian to avoid the sum over the target's dimensions**.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#jacobians